# Rails Associations Not working and not recognizing classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have a weird bug that just popped up with my rails app that I cannot figure out. I recently added a new association to an existing Model and now my previous associations do not want to work properly.

```
#=> self.user
#=> <# user.id => "1" ...
#=> self.transactions
#=> [<# transaction_id => "1"...
#=> self.credit_plan
#=> nil
```

So the first two associations work fine via, but for some reason credit_plan returns nil and is crashing all my existing working code. Here is the record associations I have.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :credit_plan
  has_many :transactions, :class_name => "OrderTransaction"
```

.

```
class CreditPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, where({:is_active => true})
  scope :inactive, where({:is_active => false})
  has_many :orders, :class_name => "Order"
```

.

```
class OrderTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  serialize :params
```

Comment: 1. Did you restart the server after adding the association? 2. Did you migrate, adding the `credit_plans` table, and adding `credit_plan_id` to `orders`? 3. `:class_name => "Order"` is redundant.

Comment: @bricker 1. Yes 2. Yes 3. I thought it was needed, but I'll try and take it out and see what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright Guys, I figured it out. If I had posted more context of my files, I'm sure someone would have figured it out and helped me sooner.

So basically, when I was setting up my virtual attributes for the credit card form, I accidentally stomped on my own name space by adding `:credit_plan` as an attribute, which overrides the association.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :credit_plan
  has_many :transactions, :class_name => "OrderTransaction"

  validates_presence_of :credit_plan_id, :user

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :card_type, :credit_card,
            :number, :verification_value, :promotional_code, :expires_on,
            :credit_plan # << This will override associations, delete to fix. 

  validate :validate_card, :on => :create
```